# New vs recurring users with months as columns mysql

Tags: mysql, database, data-science, mysql-workbench

I have a order table where I have a timestamp field for each order as well as the user_id:

```
CREATE TABLE order(
id BIGINT, 
created TIMESTAMP,
user_id INT
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

I'm trying to get something like this where I get the count of new and recurrent users for each month. A user is new for the whole month they made their first purchase and recurrent every purchase after that.

| Customer Type | month 1 | month 2 | month 3 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| new | count | count | count |  |
| recurrent | count | count | count |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

So far I have this:

```
SELECT 'New' AS 'Customer Type',
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(created) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) month_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(created) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) month_2,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(created) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) month_3
FROM order
HAVING MONTH(MIN(created))
```

I was planning on using a UNION for the recurrent with a NOT IN (MIN(MONTH(created)) statement but i'm sure there's a better approach to this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *`HAVING MONTH(MIN(created))`* ?? this condition simply checks does at least one non-NULL `created` value exists in the table.

Comment: That's where i'm stuck. How do I go about counting the first occurence. If I do a where statement instead I get Error Code; Invalid use of group function.